# Google Tag Manager, auto add image

Tags: javascript, html

After adding Google Analytics and Google Tags Manager's js into my website, it automatically added an image at the button of the page. 
The image added is from sp.analytics.yahoo.com. How do I hide the blank space that generates automatically from sp.analytics.yahoo.com. (The blank space is an img with a link: https://sp.analytics.yahoo.com/spp.pl?a=10000&.yp=10027921)

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-68890793-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- Google Analytics END -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
    });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
    j.async = true;
    j.src =
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'wis_dataLayer', 'GTM-KQG6CHP');
</script>
```

And this is my html code, where I added my iframe within the body tag

```
<noscript>
    <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KQG6CHP" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

Comment: cheat way is to Inspect the html, see the classname or id of the element and hide it or make it's height 0. Hope this helps!

Comment: it wouldn't work, unless i hide all my images on the website ... cuz it added right above the </body> tag